# Update symlinks by scripting?

Tags: symlink

I have a directory which contains many symlinks which point to other directories. 
Now I would like to rename a common ancestral directory of the linked directories by the symlinks, and also have symlinks pointing to the same directories except with renamed pathnames.
For example, the symlinks point to `/home/Tim/dir1`, `/home/Tim/dir2`, ..., and now I would like the symlinks point to `/data/Tim/dir1`, `/data/Tim/dir2`, ....

I would like to automate the process of update the symlinks. But there are several questions:

1. I heard that symlinks can't be edited. So do I have to create new symlinks and then overwrite the existing ones?
2. how can I get the pathname of the directory pointed to by a symlink, and then use some text processing programs to replace the old name of the ancestral directory  in the pathnames with its new name, and create a symlink pointing to the directory with a new pathname?
   Thanks.

Comment: A big thank you for asking, accepted answer solves it for me. I don't see it in the "renaming file works..." Q&A.

Answer (score 7):

> I heard that symlinks can't be edited. So do I have to create new symlinks and then overwrite the existing ones?

Symlinks can't be edited, that is correct. You can replace symlinks to files in a single operation with the `-f` option to `ln`, and if you add `-T` you can process symlinks to directories in the same way:

```
ln -sfT /data/Tim/dir1 symlink1
```

will create `symlink1` pointing to `/data/Tim/dir1`, replacing any existing symlink (or file!) named `symlink1`.

> how can I get the pathname of the directory pointed to by a symlink, and then use some text processing programs to replace the old name of the ancestral directory in the pathnames with its new name, and create a symlink pointing to the directory with a new pathname?

`realpath` will give you the absolute path to which the symlink points. To process your symlinks:

```
for symlink in *; do
    if [ -L "${symlink}" ]; then
        origpath="$(realpath "${symlink}")" && ln -sfT "${origpath/home/data}" "${symlink}"
    fi
done
```

This retrieves the path of each file in the current directory (so I'm assuming all symlinks in the current directory need fixing) and relinks it, replacing the first occurrence of `home` with `data`. Using `&&` ensures that the symlink is only replaced if `realpath` succeeded (it fails if the target doesn't exist).

Comment: Thanks. Why does `"${origpath/home/data}"` replace `home` with `data in the value of `origpath`? Is this a bash feature, named something?

Comment: The [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) refers to it as "substring replacement"; it's a feature provided by `bash` and `zsh` at least.